# Regression analysis comparison

Tags: regression

There are several different regression analysis. I am looking for a table/decision tree which compares these regressions together to have an idea when we should use each one of them? (for example the difference between multiple logistic with Poisson regression and probit regression)

Comment: What level of granularity are you after, i.e. what are some examples of the common situations you want a quick reference for?

Comment: @Will, thanks for your comment. for example, I want to know what is the difference between multiple logistic regression and Poisson regression? or the difference between linear regression and probit regression?

Comment: Just use the examples section on the Wiki page for generalised linear models. All the models you mentioned are GLMs, so I guess that's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

No such decision tree exists. 
Every case is different, and in the most cases depends on what is the question to be answered.
Instead of asking yourself when to apply a specific model, you may think of "why" to do so. 
The main difference among the models you listed is the nature of the dependent variable they can handle. If the outcome is binary you can either use a linear regression, a probit or a logit. However, if for some reason you need to use the predicted values of your model, the linear regression is problematic because produces probabilities outside the 0,1 interval. However, if your dependent is a count variable, applying a linear regression would probably lead to the violation of the  non normal distribution of the residuals assumption. The alternative is to estimate a Poisson Generalized Linear Model. Moreover, if you are interested in a rate obtained from a count (i.e. Count/time), you should add an offset to the poisson regression. Potentially we could go for a while in listing all models varieties and cases. My suggestion is to have a clear knowledge of both the research question and the regression tools you can apply to answer to the former. Understanding the basics is often the best think you can do, that's why econometrics courses start with OLS. Once you master OLS, you are more than half way.

Comment: thanks for your comment. For example, my dependent variable's values are 1,2,3,4 how can I know that I need to use Poisson or multiple logistics? Also if the dependent variable's values are integers number between 1 to 10, do i need to use linear regression or Poisson? thanks so much for your time.